# Valgrind suppression with using frame-level wildcard (ellipses)

Tags: valgrind, suppress-warnings

I'm catching quite a few `uninitialized value(s)` under Valgrind. The finding is expected because its related to to OpenSSL's PRNG:

```
==5787== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5787==    at 0x533B449: _x86_64_AES_encrypt_compact (in /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==5787==    by 0x533B6DA: fips_aes_encrypt (in /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==5787==    by 0x56FBC47: ??? (in /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==5787==    by 0x56FBD27: ??? (in /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==5787==    by 0x56FBE47: ??? (in /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==5787==    by 0xFFEFFFE17: ???
==5787==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5787==    at 0x4C28D84: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==5787==    by 0x53575AF: CRYPTO_malloc (in /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==5787==    by 0x53FB52B: drbg_get_entropy (in /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==5787==    by 0x534C312: fips_get_entropy (in /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==5787==    by 0x534CABE: FIPS_drbg_instantiate (in /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==5787==    by 0x53FB94E: RAND_init_fips (in /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==5787==    by 0x5403F5D: EVP_add_cipher (in /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==5787==    by 0x507B7C0: SSL_library_init (in /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==5787==    by 0x4103E7: DoStartupOpenSSL() (ac-openssl-1.cpp:494)
==5787==    by 0x419504: main (main.cpp:69)
==5787==
```

But I'm having trouble suppressing it (and that's not expected). I'm trying to use the following three rules, which use [frame-level wildcards](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html).

```
{
   RAND_init_fips (1)
   Memcheck:Cond
   ...
   fun:RAND_init_fips
   ...
}

{
   RAND_init_fips (2)
   Memcheck:Value8
   ...
   fun:RAND_init_fips
   ...
}

{
   RAND_init_fips (3)
   Memcheck:Value4
   ...
   fun:RAND_init_fips
   ...
}
```

I **don't** want to do things like initialize the memory because of the [Debian PRNG](https://freedom-to-tinker.com/blog/kroll/software-transparency-debian-openssl-bug/) fiasco a few years ago. Plus, its the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module, so I can't modify it because the source code and resulting object file are sequestered.

I'm not sure what the issue is because it appears `RAND_init_fips` surrounded by frame level-wildcards should match the finding. Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Tom Hughes on the Valgrind User's [mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CAH8yC8==VdBLqGLPNMzXGTjjdihkJGNBkX1=E_8_Kag9J-2xkA@mail.gmail.com&forum_name=valgrind-users), its not possible to write the suppression rule:

[image: The answer I did not want to hear...]